# Does being ''carried away'' mean to do something unintentional?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

Does it mean that you've lost control of yourself that you'II do things you didn't  mean to do?

Comment: Note that the idiom is not just _carried away_, but _get/got carried away_.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes.

It's a turn of phrase that means you got completely wrapped up in the activity.

Usually it's used as an excuse as to why you're late or didn't get something done!

> [Sorry I didn't do the work/ Sorry I'm an hour late] I got **carried away** playing WoW.

Or it can just mean you went too far with the activity (because you were on a roll or just enjoying it too much.

> Sorry I went a bit over-board on the decorations, I got **carried away.**

[To-get-carried-away](https://www.yourdictionary.com/get-carried-away)

Comment: state examples that are used in ''carried away'' that involve unintentional actions

Comment: Both my examples are have unintentional actions?

Comment: I mean state more examples